# keras model weights 1.x to 2.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, theano

I have a set of weights from a model developed in keras 1.10 with theano backend.

Right now I would like to use those weights in a more recent version of keras (2.2.4).

Just by loading them on the more recent version of keras the results are not the same (in 2.2.4 the results are not accurate). I can retrain the model but it would take some time. Is there some way to use the weights?

I tried to load the weights from 1.10 to 2.2.4 and it did not work. Also found a project on git:

https://gist.github.com/davecg/e33b9b29d218b5966fb8e2f617e90399

To update the weights from Keras 1.x to 2.x and also did not work.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Ok, so I found out that the weights break when I update from keras 2.1.6. to keras 2.2.0 but I have no idea why. I am using theano backend. In version 2.2.0 listed as a "breaking change" merge is removed but I am not using it.